# How does gridwidth and gridheight work (Java guid GridBagLayout)?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I made 5 simple buttons to see how GridBagLayout constraints work, and got them set up like a cross. And I attempted to try out gridwidth for north, gbc.gridwidth = 2; (Since default is 0, then 1 and 2, which are 3 columns) to be exact. Isn't it supposed to take up 3 columns across the x axis of where North button stands? But when you run it, buttons get all overlapped. Please help explain what the problem is? Thank you

```
    JPanel jp = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    JButton jb1 = new JButton("North");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.gridwidth = 2; //Here, it won't take up three columns just at the top where it sits
    jp.add(jb1, gbc);

    JButton jb2 = new JButton("West");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    jp.add(jb2, gbc);

    JButton jb3 = new JButton("Center ");
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    jp.add(jb3, gbc);

    JButton jb4 = new JButton("East");
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    jp.add(jb4, gbc);

    JButton jb5 = new JButton("South");
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    jp.add(jb5, gbc);

    add(jp);

    setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 5):

The core problem is, you haven't reset the constraints...

```
JButton jb1 = new JButton("North");
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.gridwidth = 2; //Here, it won't take up three columns just at the top where it sits
jp.add(jb1, gbc);

JButton jb2 = new JButton("West");
// Still using the gridwidth value from before...
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 1;
jp.add(jb2, gbc);
```

This means that the value for `gridwidth` is still set to `2` for ALL the other controls...

Try adding `gbc = new GridBagConstraints();` after you've added `jb1`.

Also, for some reason, `gridwidth` is not zero indexed, it starts at `1`, so you probably want to use `3` instead...

```
JButton jb1 = new JButton("North");
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.gridwidth = 3; //Here, it won't take up three columns just at the top where it sits
jp.add(jb1, gbc);

gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
JButton jb2 = new JButton("West");
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 1;
jp.add(jb2, gbc);
```

Now, I could be wrong, but you seem to be trying to make the north button control the entire upper row, something like...

[image: Fill]

For which you'll need something like...

```
JButton jb1 = new JButton("North");
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.gridwidth = 3; //Here, it won't take up three columns just at the top where it sits
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
jp.add(jb1, gbc);
```

As well...

Comment: what would gridwidth alone do? In this case I thought it would do the same thing as GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; by taking up 3 columns on the first row. Also, would I have to reset every time after each individual button constraint?

Comment: `gridwidth` is like `span` in html's `table`, it describes the number of columns that the component can span over/occupy